# Is there a way to combine 2 queries?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I would like to ask if there is a way to make one function insert data into different tables depending on the parameters that are passed. Currently, I have a different insert query for 2 different tables. Is there a way to combine them?

```
   Public Function Addguest(Fname As String, Lname As String, Address As String, Town As String, Postcode As String, Phonenum As String) As Integer
    Dim Result As Integer
    Dim usql As String = "INSERT INTO  customers(FNAME,LNAME,addresses,Town,Postcode,phonenumber) VALUES (@Fname, @Lname, @Address, @Town,@Postcode, @Phonenum)"
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(connectionstring),
        cmd As New SQLiteCommand(usql, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", DbType.String).Value = Fname
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lname", DbType.String).Value = Lname
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", DbType.String).Value = Address
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Town", DbType.String).Value = Town
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Postcode", DbType.String).Value = Postcode
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phonenum", DbType.String).Value = Phonenum


        Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        con.Close()
    End Using
    Return Result
End Function


    Public Function AddBooking(BCustomerID As Integer, bookingdate As String, arrivaldate As String, departuredate As String, paymentmethod As String, durationofstay As Integer, total As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Result As Integer
    Dim usql As String = "INSERT INTO  Booking(BCustomerID,bookingdate,arrivaldate,departuredate,paymentmethod,durationofstay,Total) VALUES (@BCustomerID,@BookDate, @ArrDate, @DepDate, @PayMet,@dur,@total)"
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(connectionstring),
        cmd As New SQLiteCommand(usql, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BCustomerID", DbType.Int32).Value = BCustomerID
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookDate", DbType.String).Value = bookingdate
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ArrDate", DbType.String).Value = arrivaldate
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DepDate", DbType.String).Value = departuredate
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PayMet", DbType.String).Value = paymentmethod
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dur", DbType.Int32).Value = durationofstay
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total", DbType.Int32).Value = total


        Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    End Using
    Return Result

End Function
```

Comment: I fail to understand the reason why you want to do this. Is this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: So that instead of making a function for each table I have, I can just use one function for all of them.

Comment: It will lead to impossible code to maintain and an unmanageable amout of parameters and a lot of if/else blocks. Not a very elegant way to handle a simple chore like database access. I suggest you to learn and use some ORM tool like Entity Framework or Dapper that will take care of data access code in a very efficient way.

Comment: @MiloszLaksa It is possible, but the resulting code would be massive, complicated, and difficult to maintain and understand. You would be better off keeping them separate

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot.